# ASP.NET Core Auth not staying signed in after browser closes (Azure AD B2C)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I've successful set up authentication with Azure AD B2C in my ASP.NET Core Blazor application. I can open the website (https://localhost:5001) in multiple tabs without signing in again. However, if I keep the server running but close and reopen the browser and navigate to the website, it requires me to sign in again. My understanding was that it should have kept me signed in between browser sessions. I'm fairly new to all this, so I'm not even sure where to begin looking for the problem. Any ideas what this might be?

Here is my `Startup.cs`, if it helps.

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
            
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
            
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/_Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Comment: When you look at the authentication cookie in the browser, does it have an expiration date or is it a "Session" cookie?

Comment: If it's a session cookie, try setting an expiration time by calling `ConfigureApplicationCookie` with an `ExpireTimeSpan` like demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-settings)

Comment: I only see one cookie (.AspNetCore.Cookies) and it's a Session cookie. I added the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` method with an `ExpireTimeSpan` of 60 minutes, but it didn't change anything. The cookie is still a Session cookie.

Comment: However, I have confirmed this is the problem. Manually setting the expire time for the cookie in DevTools "resolves" the problem. I've just haven't been able to configure the expire time successfully in `Startup.cs.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Thanks to [@huysentruitw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300910) for putting me on the right path.

**TL;DR: Creating my own `AccountController` and setting `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent` to `true` on sign in fixed the expiration of the auth cookie and ultimately solved my problem.**

The problem was basically that the auth token cookie was not being persisted across browser sessions. It would always create the cookie, but looking in DevTools, the expiration was always set to "Session". However, configuring the expire times via the options available in `Startup.cs` didn't resolve it either. I tried the following:

- Setting it via `ConfigureApplicationCookie` with `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Cookie.Expires`.
- Setting it via `ConfigureApplicationCookie` with `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan`
- Setting it via `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` using the overload to provide `configureCookieAuthenticationOptions` with a `CookieBuilder.Expires` property populated.
- A few other obscure things that I didn't expect to work anyway, but I was looking for anything to work.

No matter what I did, the cookie came through as expiring after the "Session".

So, I stepped into the ASP.Net Core authentication code (the `CookieAuthenticationHandler` class in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`) to find out why the expiration value wasn't being used. I found that `CookieOptions.Expires` is overridden for some reason (in the `BuildCookieOptions` method) and that the expiry is only set if `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent` is `true` (you can see this happening in `HandleSignInAsync` method). So, my next step was to figure out how to set that to true. I found that the `AuthenticationProperties` are set by an `AccountController` that is added automatically by the call in `Startup.cs` to `.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI`. I copied this `AccountController` to my project as a starting point instead and got rid of the call to `.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI`. I then updated the `AuthenticationProperties` to set `IsPersistent` to `true`, which is ultimated what fixed the issue. The cookie now comes through with an expiration date/time.

I don't know if I missed something, but it certainly seems like a bug to me, or at least a really poor configuration experience. Hopefully someone will come along and potentially point out my blunder, but this is what worked for me. I think it makes more sense to pull the `AccountController` into my project anyway so that I can see what's going on and fine tune it as needed.

Comment: The IsPersistent flag is usually linked to a "Remember Me" checkbox on login pages. But since this is AD B2C, this should at least be configurable somewhere. On the other hand,   doing a roundtrip to Azure AD for each browser session is not that bad as it validates if the identity is still known in the AD. Can't you configure an expiration at AD level instead, so only a roundtrip is needed instead of a sign-in each time?

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: This is exactly what I would expect. I had actually seen that same document and ensured that my AD B2C user flow was configured correctly. I have it set to a Rolling session timeout, which it says should extend the session each time we perform the cookie-based authentication. But it didn't resolve the problem. It still required a sign in for every new session.

Comment: It shouldn’t require credential entry, but would require the user to click “sign in” in the app, and AAD B2C would then auto login the user using it’s persistent cookies. That is, until you get the app to have its own persistent session.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and resolved it by **IsPersistent = true** in **SignInAsync()** method of login page. I use .net 8 blazor ssr Cookie Authentication.

```
public async Task Login(EditContext editContext)
{
    var user = await appDbContext.Users.AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == vm.Email.ToLower());
    if (user is null || passwordService.VerifyHashedPasswordV3(user.PasswordHash, vm.Password) == false)
    {
        ShowAlert = true;
        AlertText = "The email or password is incorrect.";
        return;
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(Constants.UserIdClaim, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(Constants.EmailClaim, vm.Email),
        //new Claim(Constants.RoleClaim, user.RoleId.ToString())
    };
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
    await HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo(ReturnUrl == null ? "/Panel" : ReturnUrl);
}
```

Also need **builder.Services.AddAuthentication()** and **app.UseAuthorization()** in Program.cs :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Login"; options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); });
```